CloudLinux Terminal CLI command to get OS version
On the documentation page (https://docs.cloudlinux.com/shared/command-line_tools/) there are nearly 300 instances of the word "version" and skimming through it goes in to users, programming languages, etc - nothing related to my question here.
Is there a universal terminal/CLI command to get the version of the Linux distribution being used?
If not then alternatively what is the terminal/CLI command to get the version of CloudLinux?
The server is running CloudLinux so I don't know if every distrobution uses something different or if there is a unified command.

There isn’t a dependable 100% existing version, though Debian based distros will normally have /etc/lsb-release and rhel-based ones will have /etc/os-release. Try them both. They are text files, just cat them. Also ‘uname -a’ can give you a clue regarding the kernel. Do: ls /etc/*release for other flavours and alternatives.
